# Do Ushas and Kavya Usanas indicate one and the same epithet?

Tags: rig-veda

[Ushas - उषस्](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ushas) - is a Vedic goddess of dawn in Hinduism. She  is "consistently ***identified with dawn***, revealing herself with the daily coming of light to the world, driving away oppressive darkness, ***chasing away evil demons***, rousing all life, setting all things in motion, sending everyone off to do their duties".

She is the life of all living creatures, the impeller of action and breath, ***the foe of chaos and confusion***, the auspicious arouser of cosmic and moral order called the Ṛta in Hinduism.

In [RV 6.64](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06064.htm), Ushas is invoked as follows:

> 1. The radiant Dawns have risen up for glory, in their white splendour like the waves of waters.
>      She maketh paths all easy, fair to travel, and, rich, hath shown herself benign and friendly.
> 2. We see that thou art good: far shines thy lustre; thy beams, thy splendours have flown up to heaven.
>      Decking thyself, thou makest bare thy bosom, shining in majesty, thou Goddess Morning.

---

Usanas Kavya is an ancient seer - उशना काव्येन-  mentioned in the Rig Veda [(IX.87.3)](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv09087.htm).

> Rsi and Sage, the Champion of the people, cleft and sagacious, Usana
>   in wisdom, He hath discovered even their hidden nature, the Cows'
>   concealed and most mysterious title.

In Rig Veda, Indra stated that he was Usana ([Rig veda 4.26.1](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv04026.htm)).

> अहम मनुर अभवं सूर्यश चाहं कक्षीवां रषिर अस्मि विप्रः |
>
> अहं कुत्सम आर्जुनेयं नय ॠञ्जे ऽहं कविर उशना पश्यता मा ||
>
> I was aforetime Manu, I was Sūrya: I am the sage Kakṣīvān, holy singer. Kutsa the son of Ārjuni I master. I am the sapient Uśanā
>   behold me.

---

[uSA - उषा](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=USa&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3) - means dawn, cow, aurora, etc.  If we consider in an esoteric manner it also means ***dawning of wisdom***, dispelling the darkness of ignorance.

kavya usana - means having wisdom of a seer.  So it is actually referring to Wisdom of the highest order, in esoteric way, but not a physical person.

Shatapatha Brahamana  contains verse, which indicates God love the mysterious:

> स योऽयं मध्ये प्राणः । एष एवेन्द्रस्तानेष प्राणान्मध्यत इन्द्रियेणैन्द्ध यदैन्द्ध तस्मादिन्ध इन्धो ह वै तमिन्द्र इत्याचक्षते
>   परोऽक्षं परोऽक्षकामा हि देवास्त इद्धाः सप्त नाना पुरुषानसृजन्त -
>   ६.१.१.[२]
>
> This same vital air in the midst doubtless is Indra. He, by his power (indriya), kindled those (other) vital airs from the midst; and
>   inasmuch as he kindled (indh), he is the kindler (indha): the kindler
>   indeed,--him they call 'Indra' mystically (esoterically), for the gods
>   love the mystic. They (the vital airs), being kindled, created seven
>   separate persons (purusha). (Shatapatha Brahmana 6.1.1.2)

My doubt is whether the Rig vedic seers indicated, esoterically, uSA and Kavya Usana as the same epithet?

Comment: You hv 3-4 Qs on this topic which could be simply asked 'Who is Usnas?' rather than asking is Usnas Brahaspati or is Usnas Usa etc....

Comment: What can I do? Earlier the site rules permitted asking multiple questions in a single question.  Now,  it was changed to single question policy:-)@YDS